# Fiscal data of university budgets

Tags: university

When comparing different universities, various factors are common to be reported such as number of students (undergraduate, graduate), student-to-staff ratio, number of staff, physical spaces, etc.

However, when it comes to financial data, the amount of endowment is reported (e.g. in Wikipedia).

Is there any reference for comparing financial data of universities (mainly in the United States)? Total budget, tuition fee, funds spent on education, research, campus life, etc!

I mean a comparative database, not attempting to find such diverse data from each university website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is [Integrated Postsecondary Education Data System](http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/Default.aspx), the from the National Center for Education Statistics. One of the many variables you can ran institutions on is in fact percent of budget spent on research expenses. That was just the first one I looked for. I don't know how deeply this will go into anything about campus life beyond how much money is spent on housing and student services. But this seems to be the place to go for raw data.